# Regular expression matching specific single characters or specific combination

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression matching specific single characters or specific combination of them like:
BCDFGHJKLPQRSTVWXZ for the singles
PR FR TR GR CR PH CH for the doubles

How can I put this in a regular expression ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[BCDFGHJKLPQRSTVWXZ]
```

for singles

```
(?:\bPR\b|\bFR\b|\bTR\b|\bGR\b|\bCR\b|\bPH\b|\bCH\b)
```

for the doubles

You can do this using `character class` and `alternation` operator or `OR` operator.

EDIT:For both in single expression.

```
[BCDFGHJKLPQRSTVWXZ]|(?:\bPR\b|\bFR\b|\bTR\b|\bGR\b|\bCR\b|\bPH\b|\bCH\b)
```

Comment: Can I have both single and doubles in a single expression ?

Comment: You could save a couple keystrokes :) e.g., `[BCDFGHJKLP-TVWXZ]` and `(?:\b[CFGPT]R\b|\b[CP]H\b)`